# Is a DNS allowed to reply with different IP than the one stated at the records in the domain name registrar?

Tags: dns, domain-name, registrar

Is a DNS allowed to reply with a different IP than the one stated at the records in the domain name registrar?

I am especially interested in the case where the DNS is provided by an ISP.

Comment: Do you mean whether the in-zone A or AAAA record for a nameserver can be different from the glue record supplied by the delegating nameserver?